# Get a list of all the member functions of an object WITHOUT being able to see the object code

Tags: php, object, member-functions

How would I go about doing this? I know about get_object_vars, print_r, and var_dump, but those only seem to show me **member properties**. I need to see **member functions**.

I can see the "Title" property for example, but how do I know whether or not there's a getTitle / setTitle function without being able to see the object code? (and without tediously  testing get/set functions for each variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
<?php
class Member {
    public function getName() {

    }
    public function getRanking() {

    }
}

$member = new ReflectionClass('Member');

foreach($member->getMethods() as $method) {
    echo $method->getName(), PHP_EOL;
}

/*
    getName
    getRanking
*/
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

use get_class_methods()
like this `get_class_methods('classname');`